# How to match $ in antler lexical rules

Tags: antlr, lexer

I'm working on a domain-specific language where I've been asked to provide variable names like you would see in bash.  For example, I would like to able to use an expression like

result = $1 + $2

I've tried several ways to try to match the $ using antler's lexical rules but haven't hit upon any that don't result in the $ failing to match.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remove a fragment I had been using to match a digit, I can match the $.  If I replace                                    fragment
DIGIT : [0-9];

IDENTIFIER : ALPHA[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
           | '$'[DIGIT]+;                      with                      IDENTIFIER : ALPHA[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
           | '$'[0-9]+;                        it matches.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is no different from any other character ANTLR can match. Suppose you have an identifier rule like the following:

```
Identifier
  : [a-z] [a-z0-9]*
  ;
```

You can update it to support a `$` at the beginning with this simple change:

```
Identifier
  : '$'? [a-z] [a-z0-9]*
  ;
```

If you allow a number to be the first identifier character, but only if a `$` appeared at the beginning, you can do it like this:

```
Identifier
  : [a-z] [a-z0-9]*
  | '$' [a-z0-9]+
  ;
```